# Insert delay between lines of bash

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, osx-yosemite

I have a very simple renaming script I'm running in OSX Terminal. It looks like this:

```
mv -nv  /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1140122_alternate1.tif /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1140122_alternate1A.tif
```

I usually have several hundred lines of rename code like this one for all the files I have to rename.

However I think the network security at work is messing with the code because it will randomly jack up the file names. I think it's interrupting the code, the code is so simple I can't think of another reason why it wouldn't work.

I want to try adding a 1sec delay between each line, but how? I've read that something like *sleep 1s* might work but do I have to add that between every single line? That's going to be a headache if that's the case. If it is, is there another way?

UPDATE: I have a delay working but still getting the same problems as before. This is what Terminal returns:

```
mv -nv /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1247136_alternate1.tif /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1247136_alternate1A.tif
mv -nv /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1247136_alternate2.tif /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1247136_alternate2A.tif
mv -nv /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1247136_alternate3.tif /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Remv -nvest/1247136_alternate3A.tif
mv -nv /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1247136_alternate4.tif /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Remv -nTest/1247136_alternate4A.tif
mv -nv /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1247136_lifestyle.tif /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Renmv -nv /Volume36_lifestyleA.tif
mv -nv /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1247136_standard.tif /Volumes/COMMON-LIC-PHOTO/DATA/James/Rename_Test/1247136_standardA.tifç^C^C^C^C^C
```

It's throwing up all kinds of junk in the rename part. It's messing with the file names and the directory names and I can't figure out why.

Comment: There are tools that will rename files for you automatically if you can say what the rule is for what needs changing.... i.e. all letters need to be uppercase and all underscores must be removed.

Comment: I'd bet that the "jacked-up" entries have spaces in their names. You'll need to quote those like `mv /path/2/file "/path w spaces/2/file"` . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

the following script just reads in your file of commands and inserts a sleep after each command

```
while read curr_line; do

    echo curr_line $curr_line

    return_msg=$( $curr_line  )   #  execute cmd 

    # may want to do error checking on value of error variable $? and return_msg

    sleep 1

done < ./input_file_of_original_cmds.txt   #  read in that file
```

Comment: That's not the return code, but whatever the command dumps to standard out.  The return code is in $?.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planing to perform all those `mv` commands from terminal you can make a bash alias:

```
alias mvd='sleep 2s && mv'
```

In terms of a script, since scripts do not understand bash alias (at least easily) you can built a similar function in the beginning of your script:

```
function mvd { sleep 2s && mv "$@"; }
```

The only thing you need to do is to use the new `mvd` command instead of `mv`.

Tip: In case of alias you can also name your alias `mv` (same name as the command).

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a script that has hardcoded paths (eg, the script looks like:

```
mv -nv /path1 /path2
mv -nv /path3 /path4
...
```

Then probably the simplest thing to do would be to define a function at the top of the script by adding:

```
mv() { command mv "$@"; sleep 1; }
```

Comment: Thanks! That does seem to work but unfortunately the delay did not stop the renaming getting jacked up. I've added examples to my original post, I might have to start a new topic on this because I don't know what to do now.